# Adding SORT after YIELD produces no results or errors

Tags: memgraphdb

If I run this code

```
CALL pagerank.get()
YIELD node, rank;
```

everything works like a charm. But If I expand the query just a little with sorting it gets stuck.

```
CALL pagerank.get()
YIELD node, rank
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

I don't get any results or errors. What could be the reason for this? Should I add something to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a `CALL` procedure which **yields** something, you must have a `RETURN` clause. Hence, the correct usage would be:

```
CALL pagerank.get()
YIELD node, rank
RETURN node, rank;
```

Similarly, when trying to sort the results by some value, first add the RETURN clause:

```
CALL pagerank.get()
YIELD node, rank
RETURN node, rank
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```